# How to get filtered ng-model value into cotroller

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm using "angular-jquery-timepicker" http://recras.github.io/angular-jquery-timepicker/, In that for getting short time i'm using filter has given by document.

```
{{ date | date:'shortTime' }}
```

I need this value into my controller.So what processor should i follow or is there any direct methods in angularJs to get filtered value of ng-model to $scope.date.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply filter in your controller as,

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

Filters --- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

eg,

```
   $scope.date = $filter('date')($scope.date ,'shortTime');
```

And don't forget to declare $filter as dependency.

Comment: i used this but it taking only array. and that model is object.